# when the related data is included using fluent api, the list not populated in ajax (using Web Api)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET Web Forms application (using code-first EF & Web Api), I need to read a list of items (`List<Post>`) by using ajax and populate the list of posts with the following code. However, I am having a strange problem as elaborated in the following.

```
 function LoadPostsByTimeframe(currTimeframeId) {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/post/GetPostsByTimeframe?tfId=' + currTimeframeId,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                var posts = response.d;
                //do stuff
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }
```

In my controller class, when I use the following method to retrieve the list of items:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
    public IList<Post> GetPostsByTimeframe(int tfId)
    {
        gEchoLuDBContext db = new gEchoLuDBContext();
        var posts = db.Posts.Where(p=>p.TimeFrameId == tfId).ToList();

        return posts;           
    }
```

I got every item properly (the third one did not fit in the scree)

[image]

However, I need to retrieve the associated Person data for each item. Therefore,  I need to use the following code (with `Include`) to retrieve the items.

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
    public IList<Post> GetPostsByTimeframe(int tfId)
    {
        gEchoLuDBContext db = new gEchoLuDBContext();
        var posts = db.Posts.Include(po=>po.Person).Where(p=>p.TimeFrameId == tfId).ToList();

        return posts;           
    }
```

I have this output (only first item is returned, the other two are empty):
[image: not working]

In both cases (with include or not), the Controller method returns a valid `List<Post>` that has all the items. However, with Include version, the list values (except the first value) do not show up in ajax/jquery side.

Do you think I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `.AsNoTracking()` just before the `.ToList()`.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Could you pleas explain? I found this explanation but it did not understand much: Returns a new query where the entities returned will not be cached in the DbContext or ObjectContext.

Comment: Part of using AsNoTracking is that the entities become raw POCO objects instead of proxied POCO objects that can be a reference (using a pointer to point to an object already in memory instead of having multiple copies of it).

Comment: but, I do not understand why it caused trouble in my scenario?

Comment: The simple answer is that you shouldn't serialize proxied POCO classes like you were, because sometimes you may not get what you expect.  Perhaps you have lazy loading turned on?